# Is there any CSS selector that select changed element?

Tags: css

I want to select a text input element that has been changed or typed? is it possibe to do that? like

```
input:changed {
/* my own rule*/
}
```

Comment: No, unless you use validity (`required`) & placeholders

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Annish I just want to stylishing an input text that has been changed

Comment: you can put a class by js when it is modified and do the css with this class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I´ve created a jsfiddle for a solution with jquery, where I add a class to the element when the value in the input is changed: http://jsfiddle.net/aSX5A/ :

```
<input type="text" class="textinput" />

 $('.textinput').change(function () {
     $(this).addClass("changedInput");
 });
```

Edit:

With pure javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="textinput" onchange="updateClass()"/>
<script>
function updateClass(){
    document.getElementById("textinput").className = "changedInput";
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if jQuery is not available?

Comment: Must be noted, however, that the pure-javascript version removes any other classes that were present on the element. If that's not desired (it hardly is), check if the class is already present, and if not, do `className += " changedInput"`.

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to implement this with javascript somehow.

```
<input onkeydown="javascript:myFunctionToChangeState(this);" />
```

where `myFunctionToChangeState()` is a function you write that modifies the state of the element it is passed.

Comment: The `javascript:` is not neccessary and should be removed to not confuse the readers.

Answer (score -1):

You are not being very specific but i guess this is what you need

```
 input:focus {
/* your own rule*/
}
```

Comment: `Focus` is not the same as `Change`. There is no `Change` pseudo class for CSS...

Comment: no, it just select focus element, not modified/changed element after focus out